# The Correct Way To Load PHP's PDO Drivers?

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache, pdo

I would like to start working with PDO form database work and have ran into a problem, no PDO drivers are loaded at all.

I unzip my PHP package into "C:\PHP" and then edit apaches httpd.conf file to load the php module like so:

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:\PHP\php5apache2_2.dll"
```

I then edit my PHP.ini file to load my MySQL PDO driver module, uncommenting the line:

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

Now i then create a page which calls the `phpinfo();` function, when the page is rendered, the section under PDO is empty, nothing has been loaded.

Would anyone know the correct way to configure apache and PHP so that the mysql PDO driver is loaded and useable?

Answer (score 3):

Before enabling php_pdo_mysql.dll extension you should enable the main PDO Extension

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
```